# In an Angular App, how to "pause" receiving websocket events when the app triggers http GET/PUT requests and then resume websocket events?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, optimization, websocket

I am working on an angular app where user "pre-configures" what all data he wants to see on the page.

During initialization of the app, for each data that is configured in a page, following steps are performed using HTTP requests (our server does not support http2 yet):

1. Getting the structure of the data (string, bool, array, etc.)
2. Getting the initial value of the data according to the structure
3. Subscribe to changes of this data (WEBSOCKET)

Now in this app, the loading time directly depends on the following:

1. Number of data configured
2. **Websocket traffic due to subscription of already initialized data** - I am looking for a "STANDARD SOLUTION IF ANY" to pause this websocket events until all the data in a page has finished initialization and then resume the events.

I know that having a boolean to ignore the Websoket messages would work, but am more interested in knowing if there are any standard, fail-proof, tested approaches for the same because our app has multiple pages and the data in each page is initialized as the user visits these pages.

Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.